# inequality involving power sums

Tags: inequality

Let $x_1, x_2, ... ,x_n$ be positive real numbers and define 
$S(k)$ to be the power sum  $S(k) = x_1^k + x_2^k +... + x_n^k$ .
It is given that $S(3) = 3$  and that  $S(5) = 5 $.
Find the best lower bound for  $S(1) $.

Remarks:

(1) An application of Cauchy Schwarz shows that $S(1) > 9/5$ is an
admissible lower bound.

(2) The problem appears (with a smaller bound) in the book "Inequalities"
by Cvetkovski (p. 360).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the following.

Since the domain of admissible values of $x$ is compact, the sum $S(1)$ attains its minimum. To find it we apply the method of Lagrangian multiplies. Put $$\mathcal L=S(1)+\lambda(S(3)-3)+\mu(S(5)-5).$$

Then $$\frac{\partial{\mathcal L}}{\partial{x_i}}=1+3\lambda x_i^2+5\mu x_i^4.$$

Hence the minimum is attained when some of $x_i$ are at the relative boundary of the domain (that is equals zero), and the others are roots of the equation  $1+3\lambda x^2+5\mu x^4$. Hence $k$ of $x_i$ equals $a>0$ and $l$ of $x_i$ equals $b>0$. Then $ka^3+lb^3=3$ and $ka^5+lb^5=5$. Solving this system numerically (by Mathcad), **suggests** that the minimum value of $S(1)=2.1367\dots$ is attained when $k=l=1$ and $a=1.3642\dots.$